# Permutations of matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

The question is make permutations to $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\end{bmatrix}$ 
 to have
 $\begin{bmatrix}2&3&1&5&4\end{bmatrix}$ *So he made the following*:
$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2&3&4&5\\
2&1&3&4&5\\2&3&1&4&5\\2 & 3&1&5&4\end{bmatrix}$
But I can't understand the startegy, and then he's asking to put the symmetric group for each!
I read it many times but with no result!Help plz?!!
Okay it's clear that we should have 3 permutations, but what's the strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a row to another row, only trasponsition is performed.

For example:

In the first move $(1,2)$ is performed.

In the second move, the second and the third item is swapped, we have performed $(2,3)$.

For each move, at least we move an item to the correct location.

Now, for the last move, we will do a $(4,5)$.

---

Edit:
In summary, to go from $(1,2,3,4,5)$ to the desired configuration,

write $1,2,3,4,5$ on $5$ cards and arrange them from left to right in this order.

First place your left hand on the $1$st card, and your right hand on the second card, swap their order, now you have $2,1,3,4,5$. At this point of time, the card that is labeled $2$ is in the desired position ($1$st location, do not touch it again).

Next, swap the $2$nd and $3$rd card, you will end up with $2,3,1,4,5$. At this point of time, the first $3$ cards are at the right locations.

Lasat swap the final two cards, you will end up with $2,3,1,5,4$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106995/discussion-on-answer-by-siong-thye-goh-permutations-of-matrix).